# How to populate localstorage key value in Ng Field

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-form

I have a field that uses the Ng Directive for the required validation but i want to by default populate it with the value of my localstorage key `localstorage.getItem('actreel');`

**FIELD**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-8">
    <input id="batchno" type="text" (ngModel)="model.reelno" name="reelno" #reelno="ngModel" placeholder="Reel No. *" value="" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 rqderror" [hidden]="reelno.valid || reelno.untouched"> 
    Reel is required
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should feel it in your ts controller in ngOnInit event like this :

```
 ngOnInit(){
     this.actreel = localstorage.getItem('actreel');
 }
```

And then use it in your view field :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-8">
    <input id="batchno" type="text" [(ngModel)]="actreel" name="reelno" #reelno="ngModel" placeholder="Reel No. *" value="" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12 rqderror" [hidden]="reelno.valid || reelno.untouched"> 
    Reel is required
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u show me where i have to use the code in controller